# Where does the filter for Ehcache 3 simple web page caching call the cache?

Tags: caching, ehcache, ehcache-3

I am trying to cache a simple web page in Ehcache. Thanks to some help from another SO post I discovered that I need to implement my own filter based on Ehcache 2 code. When I look at the [filter](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-web/2.0.1/net/sf/ehcache/constructs/web/filter/SimplePageCachingFilter.java) I don't understand it. Where does it ever call the cache to return a value? Here is my implementation (quite possibly wrong):

```
package com.sentiment360.pulse.cache;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.xml.bind.Element;
import org.ehcache.Cache;
import org.ehcache.CacheManager;
import org.ehcache.config.Configuration;
import static org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManager;
import org.ehcache.core.Ehcache;
import org.ehcache.event.CacheEvent;
import org.ehcache.event.CacheEventListener;
import org.ehcache.xml.XmlConfiguration;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public class SimplePageCachingFilter implements CachingFilter {
     public static final String DEFAULT_CACHE_NAME = "SimplePageCachingFilter";
     private Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
     private String cacheName="basicCache";

    protected String getCacheName() {
         if (cacheName != null && cacheName.length() > 0) {
              LOG.log(Level.INFO,"Using configured cacheName of {}.", cacheName);
              return cacheName;
          } else {
               LOG.log(Level.INFO,"No cacheName configured. Using default of {}.", DEFAULT_CACHE_NAME);
               return DEFAULT_CACHE_NAME;
           }
    }

    protected CacheManager getCacheManager() {
      return CacheManager.getInstance();
    }

    protected String calculateKey(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
      StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
      stringBuffer.append(httpRequest.getMethod()).append(httpRequest.getRequestURI()).append(httpRequest.getQueryString());
      String key = stringBuffer.toString();
      return key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See in the [super class](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-web/2.0.1/net/sf/ehcache/constructs/web/filter/CachingFilter.java#CachingFilter).
But you do `implements CachingFilter` ?! Where is that interface? It does look like you were trying to "copy" the previous Ehcache's `SimplePageCachingFilter`, right? You would also need to port that abstract super class (and maybe read a little about `javax.servlet.Filter`, in case these aren't entirely clear...)

Now, you may also want to ping the dev team on the [Ehcache Dev Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ehcache-dev) about this. They should be able to provide pointers and then help with the implementation. Looks like a good idea for a future pull request! :)